# On deformation of linear combination of linearly independent vectors

Tags: linear-algebra, functional-analysis, independence

Suppose we have a linearly independent set of vectors $\{v_i\}_{i=1}^n \subset H$ where $H$ is a Hilbert space. Let
$$
Q_1 = \sum_{i=1}^n v_i
$$
Consider $\{q_i\}_{i=1}^n \subset \mathbb{C}$ with $|q_i| < 1$ for any $i$ and set
$$
Q_2 = \sum_{i=1}^n q_i v_i
$$
Is it true, that $\|Q_2\| \le \|Q_1\|$?

I thought that it could be prooved somehow by Smith orthogonalization method, but I haven't figured out how. Thank you!

Comment: Do you mean $\|Q_2\| \le \|Q_1\|$ ?

Comment: @Falcon, oh, yes, thank you!

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Consider $v_1 = (3,0)$ and $v_2 = (-3,1)$. Then $v_1$ and $v_2$ are linearly independent. Now take $q_1 = \frac{2}{3}$ and $q_2 = 0$.

Then $Q_1 = (0,1)$ and $Q_2 = (2,0)$. Hence,
$$||Q_1|| = 1 < 2 = ||Q_2||.$$

Answer (score 0):

Of course not true.

Take $v_{1} = <a,0>$ and $v_{2} = <-a,b>$ where b != 0.
$$||Q_{1}|| = |b| $$

But, if $q_{1} = 1$ and $q_{2} = 0$ then
$$||Q_{2}|| = |a|$$